# Deleted move constructor in base class does not stop derived class object to be returned from a function

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, move-semantics

Given base class A and derived class B, A has deleted move constructor:

```
class A {
public: 
  A()  {}
  A(const A&) = default;
  A(A&&) = delete; 
};

class B : public A
{ 
};
```

In such case, the following function does not compile because of deleted move constructor:

```
A f() {
  A a;
  return a;
}
```

but the similar function for B does not report any error:

```
B g() {
  B b;
  return b;
}
```

Does it mean that move constructor in B is not deleted? I want to know what is the rule in the standard.

Comment: IMO, the `f` case should compile as well, according to [this paragraph](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy#elision-3) (C++17). The relevant part: _"**If the first overload resolution fails** or was not performed, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object's type (possibly cv-qualified), **overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue**."_ GCC works for me, but Clang does not: https://godbolt.org/z/8EbcnfTfb.

Comment: But maybe I was wrong. This paragraph also seems to be relevant, which says that the program is actually ill-formed (as far as I understand it): https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def.delete#2.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yeah, https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93106

Comment: A copyable-but-not-movable class is almost always a mistake, I'm not surprised they misbehave here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The move constructor in `B` is deleted, but does not participate in overload resolution. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_constructor):

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted move constructor for class T is defined as *deleted* if any of the following is true:
>
> - T has non-static data members that cannot be moved (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors);
> - T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be moved (has deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors);
> - T has direct or virtual base class or a non-static data member with a deleted or inaccessible destructor;
> - T is a union-like class and has a variant member with non-trivial move constructor.
>
> A defaulted move constructor that is deleted is ignored by overload resolution (otherwise it would prevent copy-initialization from rvalue).

The second bullet point applies: `B` has a direct base class, `A`, with a deleted move constructor. So `B`'s implicitly-declared move constructor is defined as deleted.

However, when the return statement is evaluating which constructor of `B` to use, the deleted move constructor is not considered but the valid copy constructor is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Then why the function A f() doesn't compile? Why can't it use the copy constructor of class A?

Answer (score 13):

The move constructor of `B` is deleted, [as already answered by @Nathan Pierson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75455586/2085626).

The reason that you can return the local `b` from `g` is, as explained there, that the *implicitly deleted move constructor* of `B` is not participating in the overload resolution, thus the compiler selects the default copy constructor of `B`.

To prove the above take a look at [the following code](https://godbolt.org/z/Ev645sq3j), adding a moveable only member into `B`:

```
class B : public A { 
  std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
public: 
  B() {}
  // needs this to compile:
  //   B(B&& b): A(b), ptr(std::move(b.ptr)) {}  
};

B g() {
  B b;
  // now this would fail
  // B doesn't have a default move ctor
  // (it is implicitly deleted because of A)
  // and the default copy ctor is not valid
  return b; 
}
```